# Java DefaultDataTable dynamic values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a JTable i would like to fill using the DefaultTableModel unfortunately my output comes as arrays and not as new rows as i would like them to. Please see my code below and do ask if any further explanation is needed! :)

```
dataTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(new Object [][] {
                    DatabaseInteraction.getCityInfo("").get("datas").toArray()

            },
                    DatabaseInteraction.getCityInfo("").get("columns").toArray()));
```

Database interaction function here:

```
public static Map<String,List<String>> getCityInfo(String query )
{
    if(query.isEmpty()){
        query = "SELECT * FROM "+ database+ "." +table;
    }

    try {
        Statement stmt = getConn().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();


        //Get Column names
        List<String> cNames = new ArrayList();
        List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++){
            cNames.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
        }

        //Get Data
        while (rs.next()) {
            List<String> tempResults = new ArrayList();

            for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                tempResults.add(rs.getString(i));

                if(i == rsmd.getColumnCount()){
                    results.add(tempResults);

                }

            }
        }


        HashMap map =new HashMap();
        map.put("columns",cNames);
        map.put("datas",results);
        System.out.println(map);
        return map;

    }
```

The output i get in my console is: {columns=[username, password, free], datas=[[hej, hej, 1], [Brugernavn, Password, 1], [Brugernavn1, Password, 0], [test1, test2, 1], [, , 1]]} Which looks fine to me but as i said earlier it just get append it as arrays and not one array - new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create your own **DefaultTableModel** by using **Vectors**.
You can use something like that:

```
public static DefaultTableModel createModel(ResultSet rs){
   DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
   Vector rowVectors = new Vector();
   Vector columnHeaderVector = new Vector();

     //To get rows correctly
     int columncount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

     //Iterating all data and creating rows vector
     while(rs.next())
     {
         //It seems confusing to newbies,
         //for defaultTableModel we need a vector containing rows(as a vector)
         Vector singleRow = new Vector();
         for(int i=1;i<=columncount;i++)
         {
             singleRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
         }
         rowVectors.addElement(singleRow);
     }

     //Creating header for table
     for(int i=1;i<=columncount;i++)
     {
         columnHeaderVector.addElement(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
     }

   //Setting vectors to the model
   dtm.setDataVector(rowVectors, columnHeaderVector);
   return dtm;      }
```

**IN YOUR MAIN METHOD OR WHERE YOU CREATE JTable**

```
ResultSet rs;
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
DefaultTableModel dtm = createModel(rs);
dataTable.setModel(dtm);
```

There may be some errors I wrote it here and should be try/catch block too, but you can fix and add them :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! this adds the column names just fine! but i do however not add any data? do you know why? :)

Comment: because required to add a new DefaultTableModel to the JTable (a new loop  to creates a model)

Comment: @PatrickHansen add Sytem.out.println(rs.getObject(i)); before singleRow.addELement(rs.getObject(i)); and check if it gets data well from the database. if not then you should check your query and database.

Comment: @mKorbel No I think it is not necessary.  Patrick, after you called this method and assigned it to a DefaultTableModel you can call only dataTable.setModel(yourModelName); I will edit the post maybe it helps to other users too